# Why does "iront au pas" mean "will walk"?

Tags: expressions, verbes

So I know that **ils iront** means **they will go** but I can't seem to get why **iront au pas** mean ***they will walk***. I'll appreciate your help greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than specifically "to walk", "*aller au pas*" refers to **[a speed of walk](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_pas)**. It can be understood as the relaxed, slow speed that you take when you are not in a rush.

It mainly refers to the speed of a walking horse:

> [Au pas](https://adadamondadou.com/le-cheval-au-pas/), au trot, au galop... Ce cheval obéit au doigt et à l’œil !

Actually, this gave a more modern version... [With cars](https://fr.glosbe.com/fr/fr/rouler%20au%20pas)!

> Dans un parking, nous devons rouler au pas et rester en première vitesse.

And it can also refer to the military vocabulary:

> Pendant le défilé, les soldats marchent au [pas (cadencé)](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/11161/pas-cadence/).

[And](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas#fr) [much more](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pas).

**Edit**: as Jonathan said in his answer, "*au pas*" can also refer to a form of submission. Honestly, this word is used for so many things that it would deserve a full article.

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise we should see the expression in context. However in general "aller au pas" is a French expression for obeying orders. Another meaning for example when talking about someone driving could potentially be to be "moving at the speed of someone walking".